# cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build an interactive scatter-plot using shiny.  Using the iris data, I would like to have a user select the x and y dimensions of a scatter plot *petal vs sepal) and then output a simple scatter plot of the selected dimensions.  Pretty straightforward.

First I needed to build a function that allows me to pass strings representing the dimensions to ggplot.  I did this and tested it with static data.  Works fine.

Next I define two dropdowns and two subsequent strings (using shiny) for petal and sepal dimensions (these are my x and y axis).

I next set the two string variables using shiny's reactive() function using a switch statement.

This appears to be where things go wrong.

The error I get is: **Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'**

I've taken a number of steps to debug my code.  I first plugged in hard coded dimensions (e.g. "Petal.Length") into the final line of my code output$myplot = renderPlot({myplotfunct( ...

This works great.  The plot renders as I expect it to.

I then added a debug line to track the value of the string I am passing this plot function.  Bingo.  It's empty.  Why is it *empty*??  Seems like it should be passed a value from the UI.r file.

Code is below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for dataset viewer application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Shiny Text"),

# Sidebar with controls to select a dataset and specify the
# number of observations to view
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset1", "Choose a Sepal Measure:", 
              choices = c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width")),

    selectInput("dataset2", "Choose a Petal Measure:", 
              choices = c("Petal Length", "Petal Width"))
 ),

 # Main Scatter Plot
 mainPanel(

   textOutput("testvar"),

   plotOutput("myplot")
   )
  )
))
```

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

library(ggplot2)

#Define a function to plot passed string variables in ggplot

myplotfunct = function(df, x_string, y_string) {
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x = x_string, y = y_string)) + geom_point()
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# Sepal Inputs
datasetInput1 <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset1,
       "Sepal Length" = "Sepal.Length",
       "Sepal Width" = "Sepal.Width")
})

# Petal Inputs
datasetInput2 <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset2,
       "Petal Length" = "Petal.Length",
       "Petal Width" = "Petal.Width")
})

#Debug print value of sting being passed
output$testvar = renderText(print(datasetInput1))

# Plot
output$myplot = renderPlot({myplotfunct(iris, datasetInput1, datasetInput2)})

})
```

Comment: Do you need to use `datasetInput1(), datasetInput2()` in your `myplotfunct()` call?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The call to datasetInput1 and datasetInput2 in the two last lines is the reason of the error.

You should instead call datasetInput1() and datasetInput2().
Otherwise R tries to convert the function to char. It should be:

```
#Debug print value of sting being passed
output$testvar = renderText(print(datasetInput1()))

# Plot
output$myplot = renderPlot({myplotfunct(iris, datasetInput1(), datasetInput2())})
```

The `()` allows you to get the value of the reactive element rather than interact with the reactive element itself. This is a pretty fundamental concept with Shiny and if that's not something you are yet familiar yet, perhaps revisit the [shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/).

Just by adding the (), the error disappears as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: This answer solves this specific problem, but doesn't tell me what the root cause was.

Comment: Please read it again: "R tries to convert the function to char" if you don't put the ()