# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm hoping someone can help me to figure out the issue with my code. I'm trying to figure out the issue with my code for like 5 hours and checked these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430171/r-shiny-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812633/cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-character) but couldn't figure out the issue with my code
I'm trying to build a Shiny app but when I run my code, I keep getting the error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Date`.
ℹ `Date = ymd(Date)`.
x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

It looks like the issue is with creating the columns Date and Month but I have them in my data as you can see in this snapshot of my data :

[image]

This is my code for reading my data and wrangle data

```
#Read and wrangle data 
dvc_read <- st_read("/Users/Desktop/shap/accident_data.shp",  # shapefile stored in repo
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE  # read factor columns as character columns
) 


dvc_wrangle <- dvc_read %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%  # transform coords to latlong
  # decapitalise everything for easy handling
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, tolower) %>%  # simplify strings
  # deal with dates
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(Date), # the issue is with line 
    Month = case_when( # and this line
      Month == 1 ~  "Jan", Month == 2 ~  "Feb",
      Month == 3 ~  "Mar", Month == 4 ~  "Apr",
      Month == 5 ~  "May", Month == 6 ~  "Jun",
      Month == 7 ~  "Jul", Month == 8 ~  "Aug",
      Month == 9 ~  "Sep", Month == 10 ~ "Oct",
      Month == 11 ~ "Nov", Month == 12 ~ "Dec",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    ),
    # clean up strings (not perfect)
    Severity = if_else(Severity %in% c("1", "2", "3"), "unknown", Severity),
    Accident.Description = if_else(Accident.Description == "Road closed", "Road_closed", Accident.Description),
    City = if_else(str_detect(City, "x") == TRUE, "unknown", City),
    City = if_else(
      City %in% c(
        "Brooklyn", "Jamaica", "Merrick", "Roosevelt", "unclassified",
      ), "unknown", City
    ),
    # final name tidy-up
    Accident.Description = str_replace_all(Accident.Description, "_", " ")
  ) %>% 
  # title case for these columns
  mutate_at(vars(Severity, Accident.Description, City), tools::toTitleCase) # To Title Case


###
# extract latlong cols from sf geometry and bind back to df
dvc_xy <- as.data.frame(st_coordinates(dvc_wrangle))
dvc <- bind_cols(dvc_wrangle, dvc_xy) %>% rename(latitude = X, longitude = Y)
saveRDS(dvc,"/Users/Desktop/shap/dvc.RDS")
dvc <- readRDS("data/dvc.RDS")

# Month order for dropdown input
mo_order <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
```

I'll add the Ui code and the server code just for a better understanding

The UI code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(
    
    title = "Title",
    titleWidth = 450
  ),  # end dashboardHeader()
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    HTML("<br>"),
    
    box(
      title = "Filters",
      width = 12,
      background = "blue",
      collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = FALSE,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "input_year", 
        label = "Year",
        choices = sort(unique(dvc$Year)),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = sample(unique(dvc$Year), 1)
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "input_month", 
        label = "Month",
        choices = unique(dvc$Month[order(match(dvc$Month, mo_order))]),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = sample(unique(dvc$Month), 3)
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "input_la", 
        label = "Accident.Description",
        choices = sort(unique(dvc$Accident.Description)),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = sample(unique(dvc$Accident.Description), 3)
      )
    )  # end box()
  ),  # end dashboardSidebar()
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("output_valueselection"),
      valueBoxOutput("output_valueyearla"),
      valueBoxOutput("output_valueyear"),
      tabBox(
        id = "tabset1",
        width = 12,
        tabPanel("Map", leafletOutput("output_map", height = "600px")),
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("output_table"))
      )
    )  # end fluidRow()
  )  # end dashboardBody()
  
)  # end of ui dashboardPage()
```

The server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Value box - year
  output$output_valueyear <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selected year(s)",
      icon = icon("calendar", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Value box - year by la
  output$output_valueyearla <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year, Accident.Description %in% input$input_la) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selected LA(s) and year(s)",
      icon = icon("map-o", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Value box - total in your selection
  output$output_valueselection <- renderValueBox({
    shinydashboard::valueBox(
      value = dvc %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% filter(Year %in% input$input_year, Month %in% input$input_month, Accident.Description %in% input$input_la) %>% count() %>% pull(),
      subtitle = "Collisions in selection",
      icon = icon("car", lib = "font-awesome"),
      color = "blue",
      width = 4
    )
  })  # end of renderValueBox
  
  # Interactive map with Leaflet
  output$output_map <- renderLeaflet({
    dvc %>%
      filter(
        Year %in% input$input_year,
        Month %in% input$input_month,
        Accident.Description %in% input$input_la
      ) %>% 
      leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>% 
      addAwesomeMarkers(
        icon = awesomeIcons(
          icon = "exclamation-circle",
          iconColor = "#FFFFFF",
          library = "fa",
          markerColor = "darkblue"
        ),
        popup = ~paste0(
          "<style>
            td, th {
              text-align: left;
              padding: 3px;
            }
            </style>",
          "<table>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "Date", "</td>", "<td>", Date, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "LA", "</td>", "<td>", Accident.Description, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "City", "</td>", "<td>", City, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "<tr>","<td>", "Species", "</td>", "<td>", Severity, "</td>", "<tr>",
          "</table>"
        )
      )
  })  # end of renderLeaflet
  
  # Interactive table with DT
  output$output_table <- renderDataTable({
    dvc %>% 
      st_drop_geometry() %>%
      filter(
        Year %in% input$input_year,
        Month %in% input$input_month,
        Accident.Description %in% input$input_la
      ) %>%
      select(
       Date = Date,
        Year = Year,
        Month = Month,
        `Accident.Description` = Accident.Description,
       City = City,
        `Severity` = Severity
      ) %>%
      datatable(
        filter = "top",
        extensions = c("Scroller", "Buttons"),  # scroll instead of paginate
        rownames = FALSE,  # remove row names
        style = "bootstrap",  # style
        width = "100%",  # full width
        height = "800px",
        options = list(
          deferRender = TRUE,
          # scroll
          scrollY = 300,
          scroller = TRUE,
          # button
          autoWidth = TRUE,  # column width consistent when making selections
          dom = "Blrtip",
          buttons =
            list(
              list(
                extend = "collection",
                buttons = c("csv", "excel"),  # download extension options
                text = "Download"  # text to display
              )
            )
        )  # end of options = list()
      )  # end of datatable() 
  })  # end of renderDataTable()
  
}  # end of server function
```

I really appreciate your help with this issue and fixing the bug I have in my code.

---

## Update:

Here's my data using dput():

```
structure(list(lat = c(40.61955, 40.61955, 40.61955, 40.61955, 
40.61955, 40.61955), long = c(-74.02346, -74.02346, -74.02346, 
-74.02346, -74.02346, -74.02346), Year = c("2020", "2020", "2019", 
"2020", "2020", "2019"), Month = c("2", "11", "10", "9", "1", 
"9"), Day = c("6", "21", "26", "20", "11", "15"), Date = c("2020-02-06", 
"2020-11-21", "2019-10-26", "2020-09-20", "2020-01-11", "2019-09-15"
), Accident.Description = c("Right lane blocked", "Two lanes blocked", 
"Two lanes blocked", "Right lane blocked", "Right lane blocked", 
"One lane blocked"), Severity = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-74.02346, 40.61955), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -74.02346, 
ymin = 40.61955, xmax = -74.02346, ymax = 40.61955), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "NAD83", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4269]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(lat = NA_integer_, 
long = NA_integer_, Year = NA_integer_, Month = NA_integer_, 
Day = NA_integer_, Date = NA_integer_, Accident.Description = NA_integer_, Severity = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"))
```

## Update II:

Thank you all for helping! I really appreciate all the answers you gave me!! I fixed the issues with the code but I'm still facing issues with one column which is the "accident.description" column.
Although I changed the name to be "accident" where I thought the dot caused the issue but couldn't figure it out.
The error message for this column below:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `accident.description`.
ℹ `accident.description = if_else(...)`.
x object 'accident.description' not found
```

This is my updated code:

```
dvc_wrangle <- dvc_read %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%  # transform coords to latlong
  # decapitalise everything for easy handling
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, tolower) %>%  # simplify strings
  # deal with dates
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(date),
    Month = case_when(
      month == 1 ~  "Jan", month == 2 ~  "Feb",
      month == 3 ~  "Mar", month == 4 ~  "Apr",
      month == 5 ~  "May", month == 6 ~  "Jun",
      month == 7 ~  "Jul", month == 8 ~  "Aug",
      month == 9 ~  "Sep", month == 10 ~ "Oct",
      month == 11 ~ "Nov", month == 12 ~ "Dec",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    ),
    # clean up strings (not perfect)
    Severity = if_else(severity %in% c("1", "2", "3"), "unknown", severity),
    accident.description = if_else(accident.description == "Road closed", "Road_closed", accident.description),
    City = if_else(str_detect(city, "x") == TRUE, "unknown", city),
    City = if_else(
      city %in% c(
        "Brooklyn", "Jamaica", "Merrick", "Roosevelt", "unclassified",
      ), "unknown", city
    ),
    # final name tidy-up
    Accident.Description = str_replace_all(Accident.Description, "_", " ")
  ) %>% 
  # title case for these columns
  mutate_at(vars(Severity, Accident.Description, City), tools::toTitleCase) # To Title Case
```

I changed the Road closed to be "road closed" and the name of the column to be "accident" like this but still getting the same error message:

```
   Accident = if_else(accident %in% c("Road closed", "Two lanes blocked", "One lane blocked"), "unknown", accident),
```

## Update III:

Thank you all for all the help and support guys! You all are amazing!
I fixed the code based on your notes and regarding Update II,
I changed the "Accident.Description" column name on the LHS to be in the upper case instead of small case. However, I get a new error message:

```
Error in rename.sf(.tbl, !!!syms) : 
  internal error: can't find `agr` columns
```

This is the modified code:

```
dvc_wrangle <- dvc_read %>% 
  st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%  # transform coords to latlong
  # decapitalise everything for easy handling
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, tolower) %>%  # simplify strings
  # deal with dates
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(date),
    Month = case_when(
      month == 1 ~  "Jan", month == 2 ~  "Feb",
      month == 3 ~  "Mar", month == 4 ~  "Apr",
      month == 5 ~  "May", month == 6 ~  "Jun",
      month == 7 ~  "Jul", month == 8 ~  "Aug",
      month == 9 ~  "Sep", month == 10 ~ "Oct",
      month == 11 ~ "Nov", month == 12 ~ "Dec",
      TRUE ~ "Unknown"
    ),
    # clean up strings (not perfect)
    Severity = if_else(severity %in% c("1", "2", "3"), "unknown", severity),
    Accident.Description = if_else(accident.description == "Road closed", "Road_closed", accident.description),
    City = if_else(str_detect(city, "x") == TRUE, "unknown", city),
    City = if_else(
      city %in% c(
        "Brooklyn", "Jamaica", "Merrick", "Roosevelt", "unclassified",
      ), "unknown", city
    ),
    # final name tidy-up
    Accident.Description = str_replace_all(accident.description, "_", " ")
  ) %>% 
  # title case for these columns
  mutate_at(vars(Severity, Accident.Description, City), tools::toTitleCase) # To Title Case
```

Comment: Hello, can you add the code to remake a subset of your data with `dput()`? (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info)

Comment: I just updated my question and added the data. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Diagnosis

Your issue is fairly simple. Once the `Date` column is renamed as `date`

> ```
>   # decapitalise everything for easy handling
>   rename_all(tolower) %>%
> ```

then that problematic line

> ```
>   # deal with dates
>   mutate(
>     Date = ymd(Date), # the issue is with line
> ```

contains an expression `ymd(Date)` that refers to a *nonexistent* column `Date`.

So R searches outside the [data mask](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#data-masks) for something named `Date`...and the first thing it finds is the **function** [`lubridate::Date()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/date_utils.html), which has (presumably) been loaded into your workspace as `Date`, via `library(lubridate)`. Note that functions are also known as [**"closures"**](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#first-class-functions) in R.

In that problematic expression

> ```
> ymd(Date)
> ```

you are thus supplying a closure as input to [`ymd()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html), which [expects](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html#arguments-1) a `character` vector. Hence the error:

> ```
> x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
> ```

## Solution

Simply alter your code to reference the `date` column, which is now *lowercase*.

```
  # deal with dates
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(date),
    #          ^^^^
```

## Warning

As observed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789340) by [@bretauv](https://stackoverflow.com/u/11598948), there are further errors later in your code. Some you can fix by making the same correction to other column names.

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked with the other column but still having issues with the "accident.description" column.

Comment: @Reta Would you kindly update your `dvc_read` sample?

Comment: @Reta As for your **Update II**, I'm unable to reproduce that error.  You *did* correct the code on the right hand side (RHS), so it refers to existing lowercase columns like `date` and `month` and `accident.description`.  You've also kept the LHS in the uppercase convention: `Date =` and `Month =`; **but `accident.description =` is the odd one out**.  Try changing the LHS to the uppercase `Accident.Description =`, while still keeping the lowercase `accident.description` on the RHS.

Comment: @Reta Any luck?

Comment: I changed the accident. description on LHS in the upper case as you see in the updated question, however, I still get the error message "Error in rename.sf(.tbl, !!!syms) :  internal error: can't find `agr` columns". I don't have "agr" column and I'm searching for a similar post that talks about this error message but no luck. Do you have an idea of what could be the problem here? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Reta I'm unable to reproduce this error.  I ran your sample dataset on your workflow from **Update III**, and it ran successfully!  Maybe try reinstalling the **`sf`** package?

Comment: @Reta I found the issue [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1483) on the **`sf`** GitHub page.  It was supposedly [fixed](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/commit/5e5268b798b84b1e26e18c9b0fa5aec72640fb40) in September 2020...

Comment: Thank you@Greg! I reinstalled the sf package, and I still have the issue. For the link, you shared, I don't know how to apply it. I have already updated the SF package and will keep looking for solutions. I really appreciate your help, Greg!

Comment: I think I know why I have this issue. I'm using shapefile data not CSV data. The sample dataset I provided you was CSV, but I'm using the shapefile format in my code.. when I try to run the data as CSV format, I get the error message: Error in UseMethod("st_transform") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "data.frame". Using shapefile format will assign the geometry type and the decoding CRS. Can I share with you the shapefile and try to run it on your end and see if it produced the same error I have. Thank you Greg!

Comment: @Reta It looks like the shapefile format has compatibility issues with `rename_all()`. Perhaps this should be posted as a separate question, complete with a `dput()` of your shapefile.  Right now, I would suggest that you simply replace the line `replace_all(tolower)` with the line `\`names<-\`(tolower(names(.)))`.

Comment: I replaced "replace_all(tolower) with the line `names<-`(tolower(names(.)))" and I still face the same issue. I posted my question as a separate question here with the shapefile data sample  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852093/error-in-rename-sf-tbl-syms-internal-error-cant-find-agr-columns. I hope I can get thoughts regarding the error message

Answer (score 2):

You put every column name to lowercase with `rename_all(tolower)`. Therefore, column `Date` doesn't exist but column `date` does. Replacing `Date` by `date` works.

You have to fix that for all other column names in `mutate()`. Also, you modify the variable `City` but it is not in the data you provide (perhaps you just forgot to include it).

I didn't run the app but this should fix your `dplyr` error.

Comment: Thank you @bretauv ! really appreciate your help